# Copy properties from child to parent?

Tags: javascript

Given the following data, how would I iterate through it copying `parent.parentName` from the child (`driver`) into the parent (`businessArea`) and from `type` to `product`?

I am normally alright at figuring out data manipulations like this but I am coming up blank for ideas because I cannot `map` or `forEach` over the data (since it is an object). I am also trying to keep it functional if possible.

```
{
    "businessArea": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "displayOrder": 10,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "displayOrder": 20,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "displayOrder": 30,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        }
    ],
    "driver": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "displayOrder": 10,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 1,
                "parentName": "businessArea"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "displayOrder": 20,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 2,
                "parentName": "businessArea"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "displayOrder": 30,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 2,
                "parentName": "businessArea"
            }
        }
    ],
    "product": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "displayOrder": 10,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "displayOrder": 20,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "displayOrder": 30,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        }
    ],
    "type": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "displayOrder": 10,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 1,
                "parentName": "product"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "displayOrder": 20,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 1,
                "parentName": "product"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "displayOrder": 30,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 2,
                "parentName": "product"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Desired outcome example:**

Each parent element would get a new element `childName`, which would point to the correct child as denoted by `parentName` in the child.

```
{
    "businessArea": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "displayOrder": 10,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "childName": "driver"  // copied
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "displayOrder": 20,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "childName": "driver"  // copied
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "displayOrder": 30,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "childName": "driver"  // copied
        }
    ],
```

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: According to your structure, `businessArea` and `driver` are siblings, not parent/child.

Comment: Sorry, I have not explained myself very well. I have added an example of my desired outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this accomplishes what you want

```js
['type','driver'].forEach(k=>{
   data[k].forEach(({parent})=>{
      const match = data[parent.parentName].find(({id})=> id===parent.id)
      match.childName = k; // TODO: make sure match exists first
   });
});

console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script>
  var data = {
    "businessArea": [{
        "id": 1,
        "displayOrder": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "displayOrder": 20
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "displayOrder": 30
      }
    ],
    "driver": [{
        "id": 1,
        "displayOrder": 10,
        "parent": {
          "id": 1,
          "parentName": "businessArea"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "displayOrder": 20,
        "parent": {
          "id": 2,
          "parentName": "businessArea"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "displayOrder": 30,
        "parent": {
          "id": 2,
          "parentName": "businessArea"
        }
      }
    ],
    "product": [{
        "id": 1,
        "displayOrder": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "displayOrder": 20
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "displayOrder": 30
      }
    ],
    "type": [{
        "id": 1,
        "displayOrder": 10,
        "parent": {
          "id": 1,
          "parentName": "product"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "displayOrder": 20,
        "parent": {
          "id": 1,
          "parentName": "product"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "displayOrder": 30,
        "parent": {
          "id": 2,
          "parentName": "product"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, when `obj` is your object:

```js
var obj = {
    "businessArea": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "displayOrder": 10,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "displayOrder": 20,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "displayOrder": 30,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        }
    ],
    "driver": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "displayOrder": 10,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 1,
                "parentName": "businessArea"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "displayOrder": 20,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 2,
                "parentName": "businessArea"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "displayOrder": 30,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 2,
                "parentName": "businessArea"
            }
        }
    ],
    "product": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "displayOrder": 10,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "displayOrder": 20,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "displayOrder": 30,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false
        }
    ],
    "type": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "displayOrder": 10,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 1,
                "parentName": "product"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "displayOrder": 20,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 1,
                "parentName": "product"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "displayOrder": 30,
            "code": null,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "isObsolete": false,
            "parent": {
                "id": 2,
                "parentName": "product"
            }
        }
    ]
};

for (var prop in obj) {
  var arr = obj[prop];
  for (var item in arr) {
    if (undefined !== arr[item].parent) {
      var parent = obj[arr[item].parent.parentName];
      for (var parentItem in parent) {
        if (parent[parentItem].id === arr[item].parent.id) {
          parent[parentItem].childName = prop;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```